# Gridview didn't display on page load in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
                    {
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_selectlendingstatus", con);
                        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", txtstudentid.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid", txtbookid.Text.Trim());
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status.Text.Trim());
                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" EnablePersistedSelection="True" BackColor="White" 
        Height="240px" 
        Width="755px">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Student_Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_id" HeaderText="Book_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Book_id" />                 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_name" HeaderText="Book_name" SortExpression="Book_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Author_name" HeaderText="Author_name" SortExpression="Author_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Publisher_name" HeaderText="Publish_name" SortExpression="Publisher_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Publish_date" HeaderText="Publish_date" SortExpression="Publish_date" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status" /> 
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_selectlendingstatus

AS
Begin
select * from book_lending left outer join studentlibrary ON studentlibrary.Book_id=book_lending.bookid
End
```

I'm new to .net..

In page load, i need o display gridview.

I tried above source code, but when i run gridview didn't show.

It shows error, sp_selectlendingstatus has no parameters passed.

So if i add parameters in sp_selectlendingstatus procedure like this,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_selectlendingstatus
(
@bookid int,
@studentid int,
@status varchar(50)
)
AS
Begin
select * from book_lending left outer join studentlibrary ON studentlibrary.Book_id=book_lending.bookid
End
```

and run EXEC sp_selectlendingstatus in sql server.

It shows error @studentid, @bookid which was not supplied.

May i know what is mistake in my code?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You are not using any of the parameters in query, then why are you passing parameters into it?

Comment: Check your query,It's wrong..

Comment: can you please elaborate? thank you

Comment: @Rani you are binding your grid so you can use the selected command but in this case you are passing some parameters those are not present in the select query.so It throws some errors.If are you passing any condition you can directly mention that in where clause.Without passing parameters it showing this type of errors.

Comment: when are you opening your connection? (`con.Open();`?)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your select query you can write like the following format.Before binding the grid you must check all retrieve columns name are present in the gridview otherwise it throw errors.

```
private void BindStudents()
{
String strConnStr =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con =  new SqlConnection(strConnStr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_selectlendingstatus";
cmd.Connection = con;
try
{
    con.Open();
    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader() ;
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
 }
}
```

Comment: I need to display on page load right? But your answer in Bindstudents().. I just confused..

Comment: Just add the Bindstudents() in page load.because where ever you bind the grid in the same page you can use only single query..:)